# Link to another part of a different html page in web.py

Tags: jquery, url, web.py

I have two html pages: `curpage.html and nextpage.html`
If I want to redirect someone to halfway down the page on nextpage.html normally, you would do

```
<a href =  "/nextpage.html#somediv> link </a>
```

where nextpage.html has

```
<body>
a bunch of html
<div id="somediv">
more blurbs
```

However, I am using web.py, which redirects an entirely different way. So, I've created a link that looks like this:

```
<a href = "./nextpage?linkLocation=somediv">
```

and in my main web.py file:

```
urls = (

    '/nextpage', Instructional
 )

....
further down
.....
class Instructional(object):
def GET(self):
    data=  web.input()
    return render.instructional(data.linkLocation)
```

now I just need to add some jQuery using scrollTop but I am having trouble turning data.linkLocation into a variable. 
My question is: is there an easier way to redirect?!
Or how do i turn linkLocation into a varibale?

---

nextpage:

```
$def with (linkLocation)
$var location:  $linkLocation
$var content_type: text/html
<script type="text/javascript">

var a = location
a.toString() not working
//var location = jQuery("#shortform").offset();

//var off = location.offset(); not working

//jQuery.scrollTop(offset.top); not working

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to pass `linkLocation=somediv` to web.py in order to redirect inside the page, just use the following link `<a href="/nextpage#somediv>link</a>`